# How do I perform a function on ALL the children (and subchildren, etc) of a single folder?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have written a (successful) function which takes a Google Doc as its input, and makes certain changes to its body text.

Here's where I'm stumped: how do I perform THAT function on ALL the Google Docs in a given folder? When I say "all," what I mean is:

- I want to INCLUDE the folder's children, sub-children, sub-sub-children. (I tried using myFolder.getFiles(), but this is too narrow: it only gets the docs that are the direct children of the folder -- not the sub-children, etc.)
- I want to OMIT any files that are NOT in this folder. (I tried using DriveApp.getFiles(), but this is too broad: it gets ALL the docs in my Drive.)
  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The relation in Google Drive is from children to parent. This means that each file has a parameter called "Parents" where it stores the id of the folders where it belongs. Instead of the parent having a list of children.

When retrieving the list of files from a folder you are selecting all the files that have that folder id in the 'parents' parameter.

Because of this you won't be able to query all the children belonging to a parent folder.

You will have to get all the children from a folder, and look for the folders in it and then get the children for each one of those folders and so on.